# Move Woocommerce product tags

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm trying to move woocommerce product tags after main content in my template.

I'm using this code:

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

            <?php
                $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
                echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as"><i class="icon-tag"></i> ' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
            ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');?>
```

But it displays product tags under related products and under some share buttons from jetpack plugin and I want product tags to be just under the product description but I'm unable to find out how to acomplish it.

Any suggestions? maybe using a function or some hooks?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','addtags');
function addtags()
{
?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start' ); ?>

            <?php
                $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
                echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as"><i class="icon-tag"></i> ' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
            ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); ?>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying this function but it isn't working. I've pasted in my functions.php but the website goes blank.

Comment: most likely you made a typo. See also http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress try to set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in wp_config.php

Comment: You were righ, I'd misstyped a line. I've corrected it and now the page loads but woocommerce description/details/comments tabs are one under the other and the rest of the web below them isn't displayed.